# Python, Numpy, User Guide 1.13.0. Is there written a wrong output by mistake?

Tags: python, numpy

I have just read the user guide of Numpy. And wrote the codes in a Python console that were written in the guide. What I want to ask is about the below image.
[image]

When I typed the same codes into the console I received a different output of `a.dtype`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2,3,4])
>>> a
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> b = np.array([1.2, 3.5, 5.1])
>>> b.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

In the guide, the dtype of a was written  as 'int64' but in my console the dtype of `a` seems 'int32'.

Also I looked at the reference book of Numpy and saw a code that makes an array's data type to int64, the code is:

```
>>> a = np.array([2, 3, 4], np.int64)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

So is that output that can be seen in the image written wrong by mistake or there's something different that I need to learn later?

Comment: You seem to be on a 32-bit build.

Comment: Oh, that is to say. i had guessed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, you seem to be in a 32bit architecture. On a 64 bit architecture, the `dtype` was indeed `int64`.